# Avoiding circular imports when base class returns a subclass instance in an importable module

Tags: python, inheritance, circular-dependency

### Summary

**TLDR:** How to avoid circular import errors when a base class returns a subclass instance in an importable module?

I have collected some solutions from other locations/questions (see A-D, below) but none is satisfactory IMHO.

### Starting point

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70927984/2302262) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70716070/2302262) question, I have the following hypothetical working example as a starting point:

```py
# onefile.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, weight: float):
        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            for subcls in [Dog, Cat]:
                try:
                    return subcls(weight)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def weight(self) -> float:
        """weight of the animal in kg."""
        ...


class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, weight: float = 5):
        if not (1 < weight < 90):
            raise ValueError("No dog has this weight")
        self._weight = weight

    weight: float = property(lambda self: self._weight)


class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, weight: float = 5):
        if not (0.5 < weight < 15):
            raise ValueError("No cat has this weight")
        self._weight = weight

    weight: float = property(lambda self: self._weight)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    a1 = Dog(34)
    try:
        a2 = Dog(0.9)  # ValueError
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")

    a3 = Cat(0.8)
    try:
        a4 = Cat(25)  # ValueError
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")

    a5 = Animal(80)  # can only be dog; should return dog.
    assert type(a5) is Dog
    a6 = Animal(0.7)  # can only be cat; should return cat.
    assert type(a6) is Cat
    a7 = Animal(10)  # can be both; should return dog.
    assert type(a7) is Dog
    try:
        a8 = Animal(400)
    except NotImplementedError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")
```

This file runs correctly.

### Refactor into importable module, in separate files

I want to have `Cat`, `Dog` and `Animal` as importable classes from the module `zoo`. To that end, I create a folder `zoo`, with the files `animal.py`, `dog.py`, `cat.py`, and `__init__.py`. The file `usage.py` is kept in parent folder. This is what these files look like:

```py
# zoo/animal.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from .dog import Dog
from .cat import Cat

class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            for subcls in [Dog, Cat]:
                try:
                    return subcls(*args, **kwargs)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def weight(self) -> float:
        """weight of the animal in kg."""
        ...


# zoo/dog.py

from .animal import Animal

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, weight: float = 5):
        if not (1 < weight < 90):
            raise ValueError("No dog has this weight")
        self._weight = weight

    weight: float = property(lambda self: self._weight)


# zoo/cat.py

from .animal import Animal

class Cat(Animal):
    def __init__(self, weight: float = 5):
        if not (0.5 < weight < 15):
            raise ValueError("No cat has this weight")
        self._weight = weight

    weight: float = property(lambda self: self._weight)


# zoo/__init__.py

from .dog import Dog
from .cat import Cat
from .animal import Animal


# usage.py
  
from zoo import Dog, Cat, Animal

a1 = Dog(34)
try:
    a2 = Dog(0.9)  # ValueError
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")

a3 = Cat(0.8)
try:
    a4 = Cat(25)  # ValueError
except ValueError:
    pass
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")

a5 = Animal(80)  # can only be dog; should return dog.
assert type(a5) is Dog
a6 = Animal(0.7)  # can only be cat; should return cat.
assert type(a6) is Cat
a7 = Animal(10)  # can be both; should return dog.
assert type(a7) is Dog
try:
    a8 = Animal(400)
except NotImplementedError:
    pass
else:
    raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")
```

This is what is currently not working; the refactoring reintroduces the `ImportError (...) (most likely due to a circular import)`. The problem is that `animal.py` references `dog.py` and `cat.py`, and vice versa.

### Possible solutions

Some possibilities are available (some taken from the linked question); here are some options. The code samples only show how relevant parts of the files change.

#### A: Import modules and move to after `Animal` class definition

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            for subcls in [dog.Dog, cat.Cat]:  # <-- instead of [Dog, Cat]
                try:
                    return subcls(*args, **kwargs)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    (...)

from . import dog  # <-- import module instead of class, and import at end, to avoid circular import error
from . import cat  # <-- same
```

This works.

Disadvantages:

- From `dog.py`, the `Dog` class is really only needed. It's confusing that it's imported completely (though this is considered best practices by some).
- Bigger issue: the imports need to be placed at the end of the file, which is definitely bad practice.

#### B: Move imports inside function

```py
# zoo/animal.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        from .dog import Dog  # <-- imports here instead of at module level
        from .cat import Cat  # <-- imports here instead of at module level

        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            for subcls in [Dog, Cat]:
                try:
                    return subcls(*args, **kwargs)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)
  
    (...)
```

This works too.

Disadvantages:

- Goes against best practice of module-level-only imports.
- If `Dog` or `Cat` are needed at several locations, the imports need to be repeated.

#### C: Remove imports and find class by name

```py
# zoo/animal.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            subclasses = {sc.__name__: sc for sc in Animal.__subclasses__()}  # <-- create dictionary
            for subcls in [subclasses["Dog"], subclasses["Cat"]]:   # <-- instead of [Dog, Cat]
                try:
                    return subcls(*args, **kwargs)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)
   
   (...)
```

This also works. In order to avoid creating the dictionary every single time, a registry [as shown in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28035685/improper-use-of-new-to-generate-class-instances) could be used as well.

Disadvantages:

- Verbose and barely readable.
- If class name changes, this code breaks.

#### D: Update dummy variable

```py
# zoo/animal.py

from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

_Dog = _Cat = None  # <-- dummies, to be assigned by subclasses.


class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            for subcls in [_Dog, _Cat]:  # <-- instead of [Dog, Cat]
                try:
                    return subcls(*args, **kwargs)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)
    
    (...)

# zoo/dog.py

from . import animal
from .animal import Animal


class Dog(Animal):
    (...)


animal._Dog = Dog  # <-- update protected variable

# zoo/cat.py analogously
```

This works as well.

Disadvantages:

- Unclear to reader, what the `_Dog` and `_Cat` variables in `zoo/animal.py` represent.
- Coupling between files; change/use of module's "protected" variables from outside.

#### E: a better solution??

None of A-D is satisfying, in my opinion, and I'm wondering if there's another way.
**This is where you come in.** ;) There might not be another way - in that case I'm curious to hear what your preferred approach would be, and why.

Many thanks

Comment: First of all, your current `Animal` class returns an instance of one of its known subclasses. So only if the module containing `Dog` has been loaded, then the `Dog` class will be available. Is it enough for your requirements or do you want all the subclasses to be available from  `Animal`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @SergeBallesta, but I'm not sure I'm following. I must somehow make `Dog` available to from within `animal.py`, otherwise it will not know what the name '`Dog`' means. (To answer your question - in this case only a subset of all possible subclasses must be available to `Animal`, and they must be checked in a specific order.)

Comment: I'm using solution B thanks to you, though it's not very satisfying...

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you only need a simple package, and do the appropriate initialization in the `__init__.py` file:

Overall structure:

```
zoo folder accessible from the Python path
| __init__.py
| animal.py
| dog.py
| cat.py
|  other files...
```

animal.py - no direct dependency on any other module

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

subclasses = []    # will be initialized from the package __init__ file

class Animal(ABC):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls is Animal:
            # Try to return subclass instance instead.
            for subcls in subclasses:
                try:
                    return subcls(*args, **kwargs)
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            raise NotImplementedError("No appropriate subclass found.")
        return super().__new__(cls)

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def weight(self) -> float:
        """weight of the animal in kg."""
        ...
```

dog.py - depends on animal

```
from .animal import Animal

class Dog(Animal):
    def __init__(self, weight: float = 5):
        if not (1 < weight < 90):
            raise ValueError("No dog has this weight")
        self._weight = weight

    weight: float = property(lambda self: self._weight)
```

cat.py: id. dog

**init**.py: imports the required submodules and initializes `animal.subclasses`

```
from .animal import Animal
from .dog import Dog
from .cat import Cat
from . import animal as _animal    # the initial _ makes the variable protected

_animal.subclasses = [Dog, Cat]
```

From that point, the documented interface only contains the `zoo` package itself and its classes `Animal`, `Dog` and `Cat`.

It can be used that way:

```
from zoo import Animal, Dog, Cat

if __name__ == "__main__":

    a1 = Dog(34)
    try:
        a2 = Dog(0.9)  # ValueError
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")

    a3 = Cat(0.8)
    try:
        a4 = Cat(25)  # ValueError
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")

    a5 = Animal(80)  # can only be dog; should return dog.
    assert type(a5) is Dog
    a6 = Animal(0.7)  # can only be cat; should return cat.
    assert type(a6) is Cat
    a7 = Animal(10)  # can be both; should return dog.
    assert type(a7) is Dog
    try:
        a8 = Animal(400)
    except NotImplementedError:
        pass
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("Should have raised Exception!")
```

This structure allows simple direct dependencies. It could even be improved to allow optional subclasses that could be added by a specific function declared (or imported) in `__init__.py`

Comment: Thanks @SergeBallesta, using `__init__.py` is another way of getting the references into `animal.py`, that I hadn't thought about. I don't like that `__init__.py` contains code that alters the modules like that - I usually think of `__init__.py` to pull/import whatever it needs, without side effects, and would not stop to think it might have some. But maybe that's just me; in classes `__init__` does do a lot more as well, after all